# Getting a a value from a Element on a page from a url and using it

Tags: php, html, domdocument

What I want to do is get the value of a element with the Tag 'input' and the name '__RequestVerificationToken' and use it, without the page refreshing... if that makes any sense.

I know about curl, what I am doing now is getting the contents from a page, then using DOM to get the value of __RequestVarificationToken and use it in a curl POST. Here is my code as of right now, the code does not work... How can I get it to work?

```html
<?php 


    function curl($url, $post=false, $cookie=false){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    if($cookie){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    }
   
    if($post){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
   
    return  curl_exec ($ch);
}
function SendMsg($body,$Subject,$RecipientId){
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 $Content = curl("http://m.roblox.com/messages/sendmessage?id=$RecipientId", false, USERNAME);
 //print_r($Content);
 $dom->loadHTML($Content);
 $input = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
 foreach($input as $node){
  print_r($node);
  if ($node->nodeName == '__RequestVerificationToken'){
      $vartoken = $node->nodeValue;
  }
 }
 curl("http://m.roblox.com/messages/sendmessagework",('__RequestVerificationToken=' .$vartoken . '&RecipientId='.$RecipientId. '&Subject='.$Subject.'&Body='.$body),USERNAME);
 echo("Message sent?");
} ?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the name attribute value

```
<input name="name_here" /> <!-- name attribute -->
```

Then `$node->nodeName` is not what you are looking for.

Use `->getAttribute()` instead:

```
if($node->getAttribute('name') == '__RequestVerificationToken'){
    $vartoken = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Wow, turns out with this fix, it works now! THANKS! :)